# Declaring local variable of unknown type

Tags: c#, variables, generics, local

How would I initialise my local variable in this scenerio?
Is there a better way to write this?

It does not have a common base type

```
var result = 

switch (template)
{
    case TopicXmlSerializationTemplate.Bloomberg:
        result = NavigatorTopicTemplateBloombergXmlDTO.MapFrom(topic, topicArticles);
        break;

    default:
        result = NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO.MapFrom(topic, topicArticles);
        break;
}

var data = await xmlSerializationService.SerialiseXML(result, Encoding.UTF8);

public static NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO MapFrom(NavigatorTopic topic, IEnumerable<NavigatorTopicArticle> articles)
{
    return new NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO()
    {
        Name = topic.Title,
        ISSN = topic.ISSN,
        Editors = topic.ConsultingEditors.Select(e => EditorsDTO.MapFrom(e.AuthorName)).ToArray(),
        Articles = articles.Select(a => TopicArticlesDTO.MapFrom(a)).ToArray(),
        Jurisdictions = topic.Jurisdictions.Select(j => TopicJurisdictionsBloombergDTO.MapFrom(j, topic)).ToArray(),
    };
}

Task<string> SerialiseXML(T entity, Encoding encoding);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the type returned by `.MapFrom()`. Do they have a common base type?

If they do, you could use:

```
CommonBaseType result = null;
```

In your case, it seems to be `NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO`, so it would be:

```
NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO result = null;
```

If they don't, you could use:

```
object result = null;
```

Comment: No need for the `= null`, since it's definitely assigned by the switch statement.

Comment: I've updated MapFrrom no it does not have common base type

Comment: Sure it does, `NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO` is returned in both cases? If so then declare the variable with that type: `NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO result;`.

Comment: @KarimAli, what's the return type of `MapFrom` method of `NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO` class?

Answer (score 0):

The common base can in any case be set to the type of the first parameter of the `SerialiseXML` signature, be it just an `object`. Say it's `object`, just do this:

```
object result;

switch (template)
{
  case TopicXmlSerializationTemplate.Bloomberg:
    result = NavigatorTopicTemplateBloombergXmlDTO.MapFrom(topic, topicArticles);
    break;

  default:
    result = NavigatorTopicTemplateXmlDTO.MapFrom(topic, topicArticles);
    break;
}

var data = await xmlSerializationService.SerialiseXML(result, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Cannot convert object to model I've updated my code